# Проверка переменных на злодейские махинации

Tags: javascript, сервер, переменные, взлом, проверка

Вот я могу с помощью f12 вызвать редактор в браузере и что-то подкорректировать в сайте. Например, есть форма, и она на той же странице (которая скачалась на комп в браузер) проверяется, скажем, на SQL инъекции с помощью JS.

Если всё нормально, то отправляется на сервер. А можно ли через ф12 поменять скрипт, убрав часть с проверкой? Тогда можно беспрепятственно послать мошеннический скрипт на сервер, правильно? Или невозможно поменять скрипт на странице и подать неверные значения?

К чему веду: обязательно ли делать ещё проверку на сервере, или достаточно на странице скрипт проверки написать и всё? А если данные отправляются на другой ресурс, который мне неподвластен (фейсбук бизнес в моём случае), значит я должен убедиться, что переменные там проверяются на наличие скрипта злоумышленника?

И если не проверяются (на ресурсе), то я должен сначала послать данные на сервер, проверить их и если всё норм, то с сервера послать на ресурс, правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверять приходящие на сервер данные нужно обязательно. Злоумышленику не обязательно редактировать исходный код страницы, ведь можно отправить полностью фейковый запрос с компьютера клиента (или любого другого). Проверка данных на строне клиента это больше защита от дурака. Есть множество вариантов защиты своего приложения и базы данных (например при помощи CRSF токена), найти не трудно, а вот разобраться - в какой-то степени да. А за безопасность фейсбука не беспокойтесь - это уже их проблемы, если они не поставили защиту на своих серверах.